# Missing html content when using dom->saveHTML in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am getting data from a website using DOM. I've tested my code in my local server and it works perfectly however, when I uploaded it on a server and ran the code, the script I created returned html tags without any content. My code looks something like this:

```
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div){
    if($div->getAttribute('class') == "content1"){
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->appendChild($dom->importNode($div, true));
        $content1 = $dom->saveHTML();
        echo "content:".$content1;
    }
}
```

In my localhost, it returns something like so:

```
<div class="content1">This is my content</div>
```

However, in the server, I strangely get the empty html tags like so:

```
<div class="content1"></div>
```

What are possible causes of this problem? Is there any way I can fix it? Please advise.

Comment: Could be the HTML isn't formatted properly... Could you give us an example page it doesn't work on.

Comment: If everything going fine on localhost but not on server, then may be php is not properly installed on your server.

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia, good idea. That may be the reason. Anyway, I'm trying to use file_get_contents in place of dom. It returned some contents for me so I'll try to go that path.

Answer (score 0):

PHP version under 5.3.6 :

create a variable that will contains a clone of the current node with all sub nodes,
append it as a child
echo the returned value.

```
foreach($divs as $div) {
   if($div->getAttribute('class') == "content1"){
      $dom = new DOMDocument();
      $cloned = $div->cloneNode(TRUE);
      $dom->appendChild($dom->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
      $content1 = $dom->saveHTML();
      echo "content:".$content1;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I've made a mistake it was not

```
$cloned = $element->cloneNode(TRUE);
```

but

```
$cloned = $div->cloneNode(TRUE);
```

sorry ^^ (hope it will work)

Comment: Thanks. Tried this out, I still get the empty html.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was supposed to be the html element but it still did not work in the server.